# How to fix an unexpected keyword argument 'axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, arguments, axis, keyword

the error code is

```
distance=tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.sub(x_data_train,tf.expand_dims(x_data_test,1))), axis=2 )
```

this part makes

```
TypeError: reduce_sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

when I search this error it is maybe version problem. but I don't know exactly.
what is the problem?

Comment: Please, specify the version, which you use and take a look at this thread https://github.com/buriburisuri/speech-to-text-wavenet/issues/48

Comment: Did you checked the reduce_sum method definition?API (I don't know in what language you are). Maybe it does not allow an "axis" parameter, or maybe it's not "axis" but something else. Try like `distance=tf.reduce_sum(...), 2)` without the `axis=` part.

Comment: you are right !  that error disappear . thank you very mach ~